# Imposing load sequence in folder connector

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Edit:

I have several files in a folder that I'm loading, but it's vital that the files get loaded and combined in the proper sequence so a 'Fill Down' operation behaves correctly.  Things from rows in File1 need to propagate into File2 and not the other way around.

So, If I have three files named 'File1', 'File2', 'File3' in a folder, and I load them with the Folder connector in PowerBI, will the contents of File1 always be first, and File3 always be last when the source list is sorted alphabetically in ascending order?

This is a yes or no question, but I'm also wanting to find some actual documentation as I am not only trying to confirm that this works but will also need to assure other people who aren't going to be satisfied with the results of experimentation.

Comment: Please include your problem so we can help you.  You are talking about combining filesbut I am missing the context.

Comment: Ok, I tried to ask in another way.  Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.